# My Node.js web app establishes new session every time I reopen the browser

Tags: node.js, session, express, express-session, connect-mongo

Every time I close all the browser windows and then open the web app again, a new session is established, that means I have to authenticate again.

For your reference, I use `express@4.14.0` as the web application framework, `express-session@1.14.1` + `connect-mongo@1.3.2` as middleware to store the sessions and `passport@0.3.2` for authentication.

Below is the code for cookie and session configuration:

```
// CookieParser should be above session
app.use(cookieParser());

// Express MongoDB session storage
app.use(session({
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: config.sessionName,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db.connection,
        collection: config.sessionCollection
    })
}));
```

The "old" session stored in MongoDB still has two weeks to expire.

It seems like the Node.js application cannot recognize the "old" session from browser, therefore create a "new" one and tell the browser to use the "new" one.

It does not happen occasionally, but always, so I believe there is something wrong in my web application.

Comment: You will need to store the session in a cookie, use cookie-parser

Comment: just edited the question, please refer. I am already using `cookie-parser@1.4.3`

Comment: Your cookie life is likely set to session which means when you kill your browser then the cookie dies.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Bradley, finally I figured out what's wrong.

This is my solution

```
app.use(session({
    cookie: {
        maxAge: ms('14 days') // `ms` is a node module to convert string into milliseconds
    },
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    name: config.sessionName,
    secret: config.sessionSecret,
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db.connection,
        collection: config.sessionCollection
    })
}));
```

For more information, please refer to https://github.com/expressjs/session#expires

> By default, no expiration is set, and most clients will consider this a "non-persistent cookie" and will delete it on a condition like exiting a web browser application.

That's why I encountered this problem.